# What are some applications for minimizing a convex function on a box with a non-convex constraint?

Tags: optimization, reference-request, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to find examples of applications for the problem

$$\min_{x \in \Omega} f(x)$$
Where $\Omega = \{x \in [a,b]; h(x) = 0 \}$, with $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ strictly convex (it has to be strict), $h:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ non-convex (it can be convex, for example sake, but preferably not) and $a < b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

For example purposes $m=1$ should be fine.

Where can I find some examples of this kind of problem that have some practical applications?

Comment: Why $m$ and $n$ when it only make sense when $m=n$?

Comment: Oh, I meant $h: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$.